# numpy matrix to pandas Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This is a simple question:
I have a numpy matrix A that I would like to convert to a column in a data frame (a Series), preserving the multindexing of the matrix. By this I mean, the i,j position in the matrix to be converted to i, j row indexing in pandas.

```
In [68]: A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Take this matrix, some voodoo magic and get this:

```
In [69]: Series([1,2,3,4],index = [[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]])
Out[69]: 
0  0    1
   1    2
1  0    3
   1    4
dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])).stack()

0  0    1
   1    2
1  0    3
   1    4
dtype: int32
```